# Include Where statement on SQL Trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, where-clause

I am quite new to writing SQL triggers and I had one working for a while now as desired however now I would like to add a where clause to the trigger so that it only fires if a certain condition is met.

In this particular scenario I want to check and see if `ContextDN like '%FA 2012%'` and if so then have the trigger fire. Here is my current trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[setAsMoodle]
ON [dbo].[LMS_Section]
For Insert
As
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CUS_LmsSection_LmsProxy] (LMSSectionID, LMSProxyID, LMSSectionCtxDN)
select  SectionID , 'DEE76E47-25E6-459B-9D38-1BCAFA44077A', ContextDN from inserted
```

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the where on the end of your insert statement

```
USE ICS_NET; 

GO 
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[setAsMoodle] 
ON [dbo].[LMS_Section] 
For Insert 
As 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CUS_LmsSection_LmsProxy] (LMSSectionID, LMSProxyID, LMSSectionCtxDN) 
select  SectionID , 'DEE76E47-25E6-459B-9D38-1BCAFA44077A', ContextDN from inserted
where ContextDN like '%FA 2012%'
```

The trigger will always fire, but only the rows matching the condition get inserted.

This is important as the trigger may fire for multiple rows at once for a batch insert so you wouldn't be able to selectively run it.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger will always fire.

You need to put the where clause on your insert/select statement

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CUS_LmsSection_LmsProxy] (LMSSectionID, LMSProxyID, LMSSectionCtxDN) 
select  SectionID , 'DEE76E47-25E6-459B-9D38-1BCAFA44077A', ContextDN from inserted 
where ContextDN like '%FA 2012%'
```

Comment: Erm that will never be true.... Where the string 'ContextDN' is like the string '%FA 2012%'

Comment: Much better, thats what slowed me down, so your answer was in first :)

Answer (score 0):

The statements in the Trigger can have `WHERE` clauses so you would just need to add the `WHERE` clause to the statement.

```
USE ICS_NET;

GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[setAsMoodle]
ON [dbo].[LMS_Section]
For Insert
As
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CUS_LmsSection_LmsProxy] (LMSSectionID, LMSProxyID, LMSSectionCtxDN)
select  SectionID , 'DEE76E47-25E6-459B-9D38-1BCAFA44077A', ContextDN 
from inserted
WHERE 'ContextDN' like '%FA 2012%'
```